# R - Image Plot MNIST dataset error 'z' must be a matrix

Tags: r

I am having a hard time trying to display a number and would appreciate any help or suggestions.

```
tmp <- train[train$label == 0,]
tmp # has V17015 V17021... values.
m <- matrix(tmp[1,1:784], ncol = 28, nrow = 28)
m # m has 28 by 28 and all zeroes 
m_numbers <- apply(m, 2, rev)
m_numbers 
#I got [[28]][[28]] 0
image(1:28, 1:28,z = m_numbers, col = gray.colors(256))
```

I get 'z' must be a matrix and when I do `m_numbers <- as.matrix(m_numbers)` I get 'z' must be numeric or logical.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, the values in the matrix were integers, I have converted them to numeric by `mode(m_numbers) = "numeric"`. This should fix the error

> 'z' must be numeric or logical

Answer (score 0):

Try: `m_numbers <- unlist(apply(m, 2, rev))`
z needs to be a numeric or matrix.

Comment: I am still getting   'z' must be a matrix
m_numbers I get a bunch of zeroes

Comment: Can you show the output for m_numbers please? Is it still a list?

Comment: I got a zeros for m_numbers.